# Can't connect Cassandra node through Ignite

Tags: cassandra, ignite

I am working with Ignite and i want to load data from cassandra table. Ignite is working on local system and Cassandra working on server. Here is the config file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.TokenAwarePolicy">
    <constructor-arg type="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.LoadBalancingPolicy">
        <bean class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<util:list id="contactPoints" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>90.43.255.66:9160</value>
</util:list>

<bean id="cassandraAdminDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource">
    <property name="contactPoints" ref="contactPoints"/>
    <!-- <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="p@ssw0rd"/> -->
    <property name="readConsistency" value="ONE"/>
    <property name="writeConsistency" value="ONE"/>
    <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>
</bean>
```

When i try to connect to Cassandra server it shows an error `All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: 90.43.255.66:9160 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [null] Cannot connect)).` When i connect to local system by changing ip to `127.0.0.1` its works fine.

Comment: How is this related to `c++`?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I am using Ignite C++ client

Comment: Check your cassandra.yaml `rpc_address` it should be set to network card IP address, not localhost http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__rpc_address

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a connectivity issue. Possible reasons are incorrect address and/or port provided, firewall block, etc.